# Linux text file processing - join broken lines

Tags: linux, shell, text, text-processing

I have problem with processing files. I except files which contains 8 columns separated by delimter pipe. The problem is that sometimes I get files with broken lines, example below.

Every time should be:

```
tst1|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
```

But sometimes I have got:

```
tst1|tst2|tst3|tst4|  
tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
```

I thought that I should in the first count delimter number in each line, when the number will not equal 7 then I should join those 2 lines. But the problem is how to do it?

I will be grateful for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your input file/text and the command you used to produce the output you posted here?

Comment: I didn't use any command. My example are lines in files which I got. Some lines looks good and contains 8 columns, but some lines are splited into 2 lines but should be in one line. Those bad lines I want to join.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your records don't break into more than 2 lines, the below Perl solution would work

```
/tmp> cat anton.csv
rec1|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec2|tst2|tst3|tst4|
tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec3|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec4|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|
tst7|tst8
rec5|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec6|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|
tst6|tst7|tst8
/tmp> perl -F"\|" -ane ' if($#F==7) { print;$x=0;} else { chomp; $x++;print } print "\n" if $x==2 ' anton.csv
rec1|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec2|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec3|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec4|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec5|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec6|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
/tmp>
```

awk solution:

```
/tmp> awk -F"|" '{ if(NF==8)  { print;next } else { prev=curr;curr=sprintf("%s",$0);rc=rc+NF} if(rc==9) { print prev curr;rc=0 } }' anton.csv
rec1|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec2|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec3|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec4|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec5|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
rec6|tst2|tst3|tst4|tst5|tst6|tst7|tst8
/tmp>
```

Comment: Hello, I need to change your code to support cases when the line is broken for 3 or max 4 lines also. Would you please help me in this case? Im newbie in perl :/

Comment: Try the awk solution.. that will work for multiple split lines

Comment: I can't agree that awk solution works for multiple broken lines